# How can I set UserDefaults for user input and retrieve that value to use for an async Firebase Authentication function?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uikit, nsuserdefaults

Currently I am using Firebase Email Link Authentication for iOS, my first authentication method sendsigninlink:toEmail works and sends the email to email from user sign up input. But I cannot currently capture the email input locally to use in another view controller for another function that is asynchronous. I try setting the email value in the button IBAction method here.

```
 @IBAction func EmailValidate(_ sender: Any) {
    let emailvalidation = EmailField.text ?? ""
    if emailvalidation.isValidEmail(){
       let _ = UserDefaults.standard
        let _ = UserDefaults.standard.set(emailvalidation, forKey: "Email")
        return
    } else {
        let invalidEmailAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email", message: "Please fill in a valid e-mail.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let invalidEmailAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        invalidEmailAlert.addAction(invalidEmailAlertAction)
        self.present(invalidEmailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)}}
```

isValidEmail() is just a regex function to validate email text, if email is valid UserDefaults should capture that value for me to use in another view controller. Here is the function that contains the async method in the other view controller

```
func handlePasswordlessSignIn(_ url: URL){
    let emailvalue = UserDefaults.value(forKey: "Email") as? String 
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailvalue! , link: link) { (user, error) in
       if error == nil && user != nil {
        if (Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified)!{
            print("User verified")
        } else {
            print("User not verified")
            
        }
}
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this SwiftUI, but it appears to be UIKit? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Lol yes! @jnpdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store the data you're correctly using `UserDefaults.standard` to store it in the shared defaults object, however when you try and retrieve it you've missed the `.standard` and are actually calling a method unrelated to getting data stored in UserDefaults.

To fix, change this:

```
let emailvalue = UserDefaults.value(forKey: "Email") as? String
```

To this:

```
let emailvalue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Email")
```